# Before validation on nested model

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have a nested model `items` and I am trying to multiply two columns together `cost` and `quantity` to set the last column `price`.
I need to set the column `price` before the form is saved and i need to also validate the model. The `before_validation` call back obviously breaks if the `cost` and `quantity` is not set before saving.
Any ideas of how I can multiply these columns together and also validate the model?

Here is my code item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :invoice

 validates :invoice_id, presence: true
 validates :name, presence: true
 validates_presence_of :quantity, :cost, :price

 before_validation :set_price

 def set_price
    self.price = cost * quantity.round(2)
 end
end
```

and here is my parent model invoice.rb

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :items

accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

validates :sender, presence: true
validates_associated :items

before_save :increment_invoice_number, :set_amount

private

def increment_invoice_number
    if published == true
        self.invoice_number = user.invoices.where(:published => true).count + 1
    end
end

def set_amount
    self.amount = items.map(&:price).sum             
end
```

end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're always going to update the price on every save, you don't need to validate it's presence, so just remove that from your validations and add a `before_save` callback, which will get called *after* the validations, so you'll be guaranteed to have valid cost and quantity fields. Here's a link to the place in the Rails Guides where this is discussed:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks

Here's an example:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice

  validates :invoice_id, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates_presence_of :quantity, :cost

  before_save :set_price

  def set_price
    self.price = cost * quantity.round(2)
  end
end
```

If you want to set the price *only* on creation or update, you can use the `before_create` or `before_update` callback instead. Alternatively, you can *optionally* set the price if it isn't already set:

`self.price ||= cost * quantity.round(2)`

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

**Update:** After some discussion (see comments), it seems like the best way to handle this might be to update all child `items` in a `before_save` callback on the parent `invoice`, since this will be called every time an `invoice` is saved. Below is an example implementation - I also removed a few validates statements from your original code and combined everything using the new syntax. Also, the `items` will be validated regardless when updated through a nested_attributes association.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice

  validates :invoice_id, :name, :quantity, :cost, presence: true

  def set_price
    self.price = cost * quantity.round(2)
  end
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

  validates :sender, presence: true

  before_save :increment_invoice_number, :update_prices, :set_amount

  private

  def increment_invoice_number
    if published == true
      self.invoice_number = user.invoices.where(:published => true).count + 1
    end
  end

  def update_prices
    items.each(&:set_price)
  end

  def set_amount
    self.amount = items.map(&:price).sum             
  end
end
```

Comment: So the `before_save` call back in the nested model does not get called and I think it has something to do with the `before_save` call back in the parent model. I figured this out by trying out your solution and I changed `before_validation` to `before_save` and when I submit the form I get the error `nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal` for the line in the parent model `self.amount = items.map(&:price).sum ` meaning `set_price` is never getting called. Any ideas?

Comment: This must be happening on create, right? Rails has to save the parent record first. Try using the `after_validation` callback to set the price. BTW... This will force all `items` to be updated on every form submission, and I'd recommend only setting the price when you need to...

Comment: So with the `after_validation` call back the validation just breaks completely  at the line `self.price = cost * quantity.round(2)`  with the error `undefined method `round' for nil:NilClass` This is on both create & update

Comment: Hmmm.... Interesting, so it sounds like your validations aren't running at all on `items`. Can you go into the console and add an `item` manually and then try to save it without any of the required fields, to make sure that you get a validation error?

Comment: Yeah it looks like the validations arent getting called at all, I added an item manually in the rails console and called `@item.save`
and got a roll back transaction for
`NoMethodError: undefined method round' for nil:NilClass`
So it looks like the validations are not even happening

Comment: OK, it sounds like you're still doing:  `before_validation :set_price` - i.e. that it's trying to set the price before validations have run and therefore, returns the 'undefined method' error as opposed to a validation error.

Comment: Yeah I also tried it with `before_save` and it skipped validation all together

Comment: OK, it sounds like something else is your problem here. Make sure you reload the console each time you make a change to a callback like `before_save`, because it is only called when the model is initially loaded. Also, make sure that when you save, you aren't using a method that skips validations (like `update_column`) or (manually disabling them via an option to `save`). If you find that validations still aren't working, try removing all validations and callbacks and then add each one back one at a time, testing each time to make sure it works.

Comment: Ok so I reset the rails console and tried to create a new `item` wioth the before save callback and all validations worked and `set_price` was called on `@item.save` its just when the `invoice` gets created it never calls `before_save` in the `items` modal.

Comment: Make sure to use `invoice.items.build(items_params)` to add new items to an (already initialized) invoice. This should happen automagically if you're doing a mass update from values submitted to the `InvoicesController`. Try adding a new `item` manually in the console, though, and try saving the `invoice` and see what happens. If nothing is saved, you might need to change an attribute on `invoice`, so Rails sees it as dirty and saves it. If this all works, we know that the problem lies with the nested attributes...

Comment: Ok so everything works correctly on `create` and breaks on `update` so this is definitely happening because the parent `invoice` is not dirty so its not calling `before_save` on `items`  I guess I could use `attr_name_will_change!` on the parent `invoice` but is there a better way? Like doing something in the `update action` in the `InvoicesController` ?

Comment: You can also call the `[attribute_name]_will_change!` method on the `invoice` object within your `update` action on the controller as a quick workaround. Or (as I have done in the past) you can setup a method on `item` like `update_price` and then have `invoice` update the price in a `before_save` callback (which gets called regardless of the dirty state on the `Invoice` model).

Comment: Alternatively, you could set the `price` higher up in the callbacks chain, like `after_initialize`, which would set the parent `invoice` to be dirty and force a save for everything. Be very careful with this though, since it is called after *every* `item` is initialized - i.e. also for `items` returned by queries!

Comment: Cool, I would like to keep my controllers as skinny as possible so I like the sound of setting up a method for `update_price` to be called from `invoice`
How do you call a method in a child `model` through its parent though?

Comment: OK, I updated the answer to show a new implementation given our discussion. Let me know what you think...

Comment: anyone know the reason why sometimes in my case there is still `item.price` that is not calculated?